# Pie chart for Chartjs - JSON Ajax HTTP GET request?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, charts

I'm totally new at this, and this week we're learning about the Chartjs for canvas and a little about JSON. We're required to use the Ajax HTTP GET request for the json file but I honestly have no clue how to call the function to place the data in and have the pie and bar chart show. If anyone could assist, that would be great.

HTML Code

```
<canvas id="pieChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

    <!-- Scripts -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="js/js.js"></script>
```

JS

```
    $(function () { 
    getPieChartData(); 
}); 


function getPieChartData() { 
    $.get( 
        'http://localhost:8888/r_tomino_assignment6/data/piechart-data.json', 
        function (data) { 
            displayPieChart(data) 
        }, 
        'json' 
        ); 
} 

var context = document.getElementById("pieChart").getContext("2d");   
var myPieChart = new Chart(context).Pie(data);
```

JSON Data

```
    [
    {
        "color": "#F7464A",
        "highlight": "#FF5A5E",
        "label": "Red",
        "value": 300
    },
    {
        "color": "#46BFBD",
        "highlight": "#5AD3D1",
        "label": "Green",
        "value": 50
    },
    {
        "color": "#FDB45C",
        "highlight": "#FFC870",
        "label": "Yellow",
        "value": 100
    }
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your `displayPieChart` function getting called? It looks like you have not defined it anywhere. Since that AJAX request is asynchronous you need to give it the callback function which you have. You just now need another function called `displayPieChart` that takes `data` and creates the chart.

That function would then need to follow on and call the following lines

```
var context = document.getElementById("pieChart").getContext("2d");   
var myPieChart = new Chart(context).Pie(data);
```

eg

```
function displayPieChart(data) {
    var context = document.getElementById("pieChart").getContext("2d");   
    var myPieChart = new Chart(context).Pie(data);
}
```

Which is able to see your data.

Comment: hi @D. Young, I realized that I didn't call it but unfortunately nothing appears on my canvas to display the chart. :/

Comment: Hey Becky, creating the chart is a bit trickier than that, I'd recommend reading through the documentation here to get a better idea. I'd essentially only copy and paste their example so it might be best to just look at their docs http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#doughnut-pie-chart-introduction